# Where is the Variables Menu gone in the new Dymola UI?

Tags: modelica, dymola

Until Dymola 2020, now and then I used the Edit->Variables menu to set annotations. Where do I find it in the new UI in 2020x?

#### Edit->Variables:

[image: Edit->Variables]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the dialog you are referring to is available using one of two ways:

1. via the context menu, after a right-click. Within the "Variables" menu you will need to select the variable you want to edit from the list shown there.

[image: Context-menu of the variable from the text editor]

If you select a variable before doing the right-click, it will be highlighted and moved to the top of the list of available variables as shown in the above screenshot.

Additionally it should be possible to access the dialog by highlighting the variable and pressing CTRL+Shift+N, but that does not work reliably for me...

2. Using the component browser (after enabling the "Include non-graphical" option, which is marked red) by right-clicking the variable you want to edit and then select "Variable..."

[image: Via component browser]

Answer (score 2):

You can also find it in the GUI in the `Text` tab - well hidden inside the `Insert` button:

[image]